# I want to write to a region of /def/mem by mapping it to the virtual address with mmap() in linux

Tags: c, linux, kernel, mmap

my code like this:

```
    mfd=open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)
    mmap(0, length, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, mfd, offset)
```

I know that, with flag MAP_SHARED, other processes can access this mapped region.

And I also know that, with flag MAP_PRIVATE, I can not write the mapped region,because of the copy on write operations.

So what I want to know is that, if there are some solutions to prevent the access(write) from other processes.

**Edited@2023/12/12**
Add the background:
My intended purpose is to **read/write** the specific region of `/def/mem` by **virtual address** in the **user mode**.
So, I write this code, but I thought that may cause some security problems.
(like, some process may access the same region during the period of [`mmap,unmap`])

> ```
>    mfd=open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)
>    mmap(0, length, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, mfd, offset)
> ```

so, I have two question:
1.If keep using `mmap()`, is there some solutions to prevent the security problems or is it necessary to worry about this problem?
2.Is there any solution without using the `mmap()`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, format the code as code and please specify a tag  for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that, with flag MAP_SHARED, other processes can access this mapped region.

Sort of.  If you use `MAP_SHARED`, then the mapping is *dynamically* backed by the underlying file, so that changes written to it can be observed by other processes *in the file* and in other processes' (shared) mappings of the file, and so that changes by other processes *to the underlying file* or to their own shared mappings of the same region after it is mapped can be observed via the mapping.

The map itself is not visible to other processes unless you make it so.

> And I also know that, with flag MAP_PRIVATE, I can not write the mapped region,because of the copy on write operations.

Again, sort of.  With `MAP_PRIVATE`, the mapping is *statically* backed by the underlying file, if any.  The mapped region is writable if you ask for it to be, but writes to it are not passed through to the underlying file, and it is unspecified whether other processes' writes to the file after it is mapped are visible via the mapping.

Copy-on-write is not the cause of this, but rather the mechanism for it.

> So what I want to know is that, if there are some solutions to prevent the access(write) from other processes.

Mapping a file with `MAP_SHARED` does not give random other processes any more access to that file than they otherwise would have.  If your process forks others then you may want to ensure that they unmap the region before proceeding to their regular work, but even that might not be necessary.  In particular, it should not be necessary when the child process immediately `exec`s another program.

Do be aware, however, that [`/dev/mem`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html) does not necessarily provide access to all of memory.  In fact, it may well not allow access to any RAM at all, but only to hardware memory-mapped regions.

Comment: @ John Bollinger,thanks for the answer. Sorry for the poor english.I think you had understood my situation.  Did you mean that there is no need to preserve that the `MAP_SHARED` region of `/dev/mem` will not be hacked before `unmap()`?

Comment: @Jofee, I mean that one process mapping a region of `/dev/mem` with `MAP_SHARED` does not inherently make the mapped region accessible to other processes.  There are ways that the process that creates the mapping can *make* it available to other processes, and that process itself might be vulnerable to hacking, but merely mapping the file does not make it or its contents available to other processes.

Comment: @ John Bollinger, I have added some background to the question.

Comment: @Jofee, as this answer already says, "Mapping a file with `MAP_SHARED` does not give random other processes any more access to that file than they otherwise would have."  I'm having trouble seeing what kind of security issue you imagine that is not adequately addressed by that.

Comment: @ John Bollinger, the security issue that I am warred about is that if someone got the address of the memory region, he could do the same mapping, and then change the contents of the memory. And your answer is that Mapping a file with `MAP_SHARED` does not give more access to random other processes, so if the process can access the file(`/dev/mem`), it can do it at any time no matter who mapped the file. So, the conclusion is that there is no need to warry about the issue (in other words, there is no security issue). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Jofee, your focus seems all wrong here. The address at which your process maps the file is wholly irrelevant.  Yes, if you map with `MAP_SHARED` then you will see modifications to the file by other users and processes, *by any means*, but (i) you need `MAP_SHARED` if you want to be able to modify the file, and (ii) those concerns are little relevant to special files such as `/dev/mem`.  If there is a security risk here (still unclear to me) then it is because what you propose to do is *inherently* insecure, not because of your choice of how to access `/dev/mem`.

Comment: @ John Bollinger This code will be used in an embedded system, as a trusted app, it is allowed to modify the specific memory. However, as a non-trusted app, it should not be allowed to do so. But I'm almost about to agree with your point that there is no security issue.